# PRISM INavigateAync Version 7 for WPF

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm new to PRISM, and with this screen shot..

[image]

It shows that Version 6 is legacy, but the navigation for version 7 is blank (?).  Can I be pointed to an example of INavigateAsync ? What am I Missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Documentation/issues/28

Docs for WPF Prism 7 has not been written yet